# ret, retn, retf - how to use them

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following asm code:

```
; int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
_wWinMain@16 proc near

var_8= dword ptr -8
var_4= dword ptr -4
hInstance= dword ptr  8
hPrevInstance= dword ptr  0Ch
lpCmdLine= dword ptr  10h
nShowCmd= dword ptr  14h

push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
sub     esp, 8
mov     [ebp+var_4], 5
mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
add     eax, 1
mov     [ebp+var_8], eax
xor     eax, eax
mov     esp, ebp
pop     ebp
retn    10h
```

From what I read, you have 3 types of return instruction: ret, retn and retf, meaning return, return near and return far. They allow an optional argument nBytes, that I guess it's the number of bytes to pop, from the defined variables. When should I use retn or retf instead of ret? How can I calculate the optional parameter, nBytes?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the mnemonic ret N, N is the size of parameters on the stack. In this case it is 4 * 4 = 16 (10h) for 4 DWORDs.
But this only applies to calling conventions when the callee is responsible for stack cleanup. In case of cdecl convention the ret should be without any numbers, as the caller is responsible for stack cleanup.

Comment: Ah so the N in ret N refers to the number of pushed arguments passed by the caller, and not the local variables as I thought. Is that it?

Comment: Yes. It's the number of pushed arguments. Locals are poped by mov esp, ebp command at the end

Answer (score 78):

There are actually only two different returns, retn (near return) and retf (far return).  When you just use ret, the assembler or compiler is smart enough to pick which one is necessary.  A near return is a jump to within the existing code segment, a far return is a jump to a different code segment.  On Windows you only have a single code segment, and thus ret should just be a mnemonic for retn.  Separate retn and retf instructions are a throwback to older days when segmented memory models were common.  Pretty much all 32-bit x86 systems running today uses a flat, not segmented, memory model.

Ret with no argument pops the return address off of the stack and jumps to it.  Some calling conventions (like __stdcall) specify that the callee function cleans up the stack.  In this case, they call ret with number of bytes to pop those parameters off of the stack.  The 16 bytes are the parameters to the winmain function.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get this last part. When using retn <something> I should be clearing what? Those 2 variables + the ebp(4 bytes)? As you say that makes 8 + 4 = 12, but the code shows 16. What are those 4 bytes left?

Comment: Sorry, forget the calling convention was __stdcall.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: If you substitute the function epilog with ret 0ch, then the content of ebp will be incorrect in the calling function.

Comment: To add to this answer: for 64-bit Windows systems, when executing 32-bit applications, the WoW64 subsystem uses two code segments - one for 32-bit code (0x23) and one for 64-bit code (0x33). The latter gets used primarily by NTDLL when making syscalls, since the kernel only runs 64-bit code, but also malware can switch between these code segments in its application code to better avoid detection from antivirus products (a technique known as Heaven's Gate).

Answer (score 40):

It's actually two types: **`retn`** and **`retf`**. The third one **`ret`** is coded by the assembler into one of the first two.

The difference is that **`retn`** (return near) will pop the instruction pointer (IP) only. While the **`retf`** (return far) will pop both the instruction pointer (IP) and the code segment (CS).