# C++ Assembly "RETN 10"

Tags: c++, assembly

I have the following function :

```
int __declspec() MyFunc(SOCKET sSocket, const char* sData, int sSize, int sFlag)
{
    pSocket = sSocket;
    return send(sSocket,sData, sSize, sFlag);
}
```

And here is its assembly code after compiling :

```
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP,ESP
PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+14]               // Flags
MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+10]               // DataSize
MOV DWORD PTR DS:[pSocket],EAX
PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+C]                // Data
PUSH EAX                                 // Socket
CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&WS2_32.#19_send>]   // send
POP EBP
RETN
```

My questions are:

1. Whats the difference between `RETN`, `RETN 8` or `RETN 10` ?
2. I have to change the final `RETN` to `RETN 10`, what changes should I make to my C++ code ?

Comment: May I suggest you get a book on x86 assembly language to learn the difference between retn and retn 10.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396909/ret-retn-retf-how-to-use-them

Comment: Thanks, I got difference between retn and retn 10, what about my second question ?

Comment: _"what about my second question"_: Make it `stdcall`? (i.e. add an `__attribute__((stdcall))` to the function if you're using GCC)

Comment: @Michael "Error: identifier "stdcall" is undefined, may i just add `__stdcall` to my function ?

Comment: @Shahriyar: If you use GCC it would be e.g. `void __attribute__ ((stdcall)) foo(int i) {`. If you use Microsoft's compiler then I think it'd be something like `void __stdcall foo(int i) {`. If you use something else, then I've no idea.

Comment: @Michael, I tried what you said, Not only it didn't change RETN to RETN 10 Also it removed the whole return :D,But who cares, it completely fixed my problem.Post your answer i will mark it as best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to change the final RETN to RETN 10, what changes should i make to my c++ code ?

To get the called function to clean up the stack before returning (using `RET(N) imm`, or through other means), make it use the [`stdcall` calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall).

If you're using Microsoft's C/C++ compiler you can achieve this by adding an [__stdcall modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), as in:

```
void __stdcall foo(int arg1, int arg2) {
  // ...
}
```

If you're using GCC you can achieve this using the [stdcall attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

```
void __attribute__ ((stdcall)) foo(int arg1, int arg2) {
  // ...
}
```

You could of course `#define` `__stdcall` as `__attribute__ ((stdcall))` to save yourself some typing, and make the code more portable.

Compiling a function like the above using GCC in Cygwin results in the following assembly:

```
_foo@8:
push    ebp
mov ebp, esp
... (omitted for brevity)
leave
ret 8
```