# How to identify the calling conventions within assembly code

Tags: assembly, nasm, calling-convention

I have got three assembler code fragments and I should identify the proper calling convention (CDECL, STDCALL, FASTCALL) for each fragment. In order to identify the calling convention I was searching for the stack cleaner which is either caller or callee. But what if I cannot find the cleaning code which I assume have look like 'add esp, 8'. Am I wrong with my approach. Must I search for other calling convention characteristics? In the following there are the code fragments.

Fragment 1

```
push ebp
mov ebp , esp
sub esp , 0x8
mov [ ebp-0x4 ] , eax
mov [ ebp-0x8 ] , edx
mov eax , [ ebp-0x8 ]
mov edx , [ ebp-0x4 ]
add edx , eax
mov eax , ecx
add eax , edx
leave
ret
```

Fragment 2

```
push ebp
mov ebp , esp
mov eax , [ ebp+0xC]
mov edx , [ ebp+0x8 ]
add edx , eax
mov eax , [ ebp+0x10 ]
add eax , edx
pop ebp
ret 0xC
```

Fragment 3

```
push ebp
mov ebp , esp
mov eax , [ ebp+0xC]
mov edx , [ ebp+0x8 ]
add edx , eax
mov eax , [ ebp+0x10 ]
add eax , edx
pop ebp
ret
```

Comment: wtb highlight for assembler code on stackoverflow :(

Comment: `add esp...` is not the only way, [ret also works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396909/ret-retn-retf-how-to-use-them)

Comment: so in case of `ret` the return address is popped of the stack and put into `eip`. So its up to the caller to clean up the stack, right?

Comment: With the stdcall and fastcall calling conventions it's the function's job to pop arguments from the stack. One of your functions doesn't have any arguments on the stack, one of them pop arguments from the stack and one of them doesn't pop arguments from the stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first Fragment  is fastcall calling convention
because the procedure has used the registers(EAX,EDX) without assigning values to it - which means the caller used the registers for passing the arguments - like in line

```
mov [ ebp-0x4 ] , eax
```

second Fragment  is stdcall calling convention because the procedure cleaned the stack off the parameters

```
ret 0xC
```

third Fragment  is cdecl calling convention because the procedure took the parameters from the stack but it didn't cleared the stack off the parameters

```
ret
```

quick marks for each one will be:

fastcall : the caller use registers for passing first two arguments.

stdcall  : the callee has to clean the stack.

cdecl    : the caller has to clean the stack.

for more information see the wiki

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Answer (score 2):

Since the return address is in the way, the typical method for callee cleanup is the `ret X` instruction (where `X` is the number of argument bytes to remove). As such, your second example is callee cleanup, ie. `stdcall`.

To spot `fastcall`, you just have to find registers that are used without being initialized. You can see this in your first fragment: neither `eax` nor `edx` has been initialized. So that's `fastcall`.

What remains must be `cdecl`, but of course you can see that it is accessing arguments above the return address, via `ebp+0x8` and `ebp+0xC`, and it doesn't remove them.

Comment: thanks, very clear. I was so focused on the add instruction and forgot about the rest.